# Spread operator error with React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm fairly new to react and redux. I'm working on a reducer and running into compilation errors when trying to use the spread operator.

```
export default function chaptersReducer(
  state = { chapters: {}, isFetching: false, error: false },
  action = {},
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST:
      return { ...state, isFetching: true, error: false };
    case SUCCESS:
       return {
         ...state,
         chapters: {
           ...state.chapters,
           action.payload
         },
         isFetching: false
       };
    case FAILURE:
      return { ...state, isFetching: false, error: true };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The specific error I'm getting is this. (inside the SUCCESS case)

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected , (27:44)
> 27 |         chapters: {...state.chapters, action.payload},
     |                                             ^
```

Maybe I'm missing something extremely obvious, but can someone help me figure out what's going on?

EDIT: I'm using create-react-app, redux, and react-redux

Comment: Why are you using `...state.chapters`? Should it not just be `...state` or `state.chapters`. Why are you using a spread operator on `chapters`?

Comment: The data coming from my API is structured like `{ mangaId: [{ chapterObjects }] }`. My intention was if chapters is empty, add the payload, if mangaIds conflict, overwrite the old data.Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how to do that correctly?

Comment: Correction: if chapters[mangaId] doesn't exist, add the payload, if it does, overwrite the previous array of mangaIds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
chapters: {
    ...state.chapters,
    action.payload
},
```

not really sure what you're going for, here

```
chapters: {
    ...state.chapters,
    ...action.payload
},
```

maybe?

not specifying a key (`{ someProp }`) is shorthand for `{ someProp: someProp }` and requires simple keys (i.e. `action.payload` doesn't work)

either way, you need either a key there i.e.

```
chapters: {
    ...state.chapters,
    chapterN: action.payload
},
```

or to replace entirely

```
chapters: action.payload
```

**edit: I see your comment**

given `action.payload` => `{ someId: { ... some payload ... } }`,

```
chapters: {
    ...state.chapters,
    ...action.payload
},
```

is probably pretty close to what you want. if you're also passing the `mangaId` as a field on the action i.e. `{ id: mangaId, payload: { ... some payload ... } }`, then you'll want

```
chapters: {
    ...state.chapters,
    [action.mangaId]: action.payload
},
```

Comment: Thanks, I was aiming for your second block of code. Can you help me verify if that's doing what I intend it to do? Goal: If chapters[mangaId] is empty, add the payload, if mangaIds conflict, overwrite the old data.

Comment: you are correct. `{ manga2: "manga1", ...{ manga2: "manga2" } }` -> `{ manga2: "manga2" }`